# Given that $f(x)$ is a CDF, for what values of $\alpha$, $1-\left(1-f\right)^{\alpha}$ is a CDF

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm tackling the following question:

> Let $f$ be a cumulative distribution function. Determine for what values of $\alpha$, the function $$g=1-\left(1-f\right)^\alpha$$ is also a cumulative distribution function.

**My try:**

1. First of all $g$ has to be non-negative, i.e $$1-\left(1-f\right)^\alpha\ge 0 \implies 1\ge \left(1-f\right)^\alpha \xrightarrow{0\le 1-f\le 1} \alpha\ge 0$$Now, if $\alpha=0$, then $g=1$, thus $\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty}g(x)\ne 0$, thus $\alpha>0$.
2. Second, $g$ has to be not decreasing. $f$ is CDF, hence we can write the following \begin{align}\forall x,y\in\Bbb{R}\textbf{ s.t }&x>y:f(x)\ge f(y)\implies 1-f(x)\le 1-f(y)\\[0.2cm]&\implies \left(1-f(x)\right)^\alpha\le \left(1-f(y)\right)^\alpha 1-\left(1-f(x)\right)^\alpha\ge 1-\left(1-f(y)\right)^\alpha\\[0.2cm]&\implies g(x)\ge g(y) \end{align}thus, $g$ is not decreasing.
3. Third, we need to show that $g$ is right-continuous, i.e $\forall x\in\Bbb{R}: \lim\limits_{h\to 0^+}g(x+h)=g(x)$. I'm trying to justify the following \begin{align}\lim_{h\to 0^+}g(x+h)&=\lim_{h\to 0^+}\left[1-\left(1-f(x+h)\right)^\alpha\right]\\[0.2cm]&=1-\left(1-\lim_{h\to 0^+}f(x+h)\right)^\alpha=1-\left(1-f(x)\right)^\alpha=g(x)\end{align} Why can I change the limit like that?
4. Last, we need to show that $$\lim_{x\to -\infty}g(x)=0, \quad  \lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)=1$$
   Like before, I don't know how to justify the change of limits (calculation is same...)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can change the limit due to right continuity of $f$. Also, check in 2. the direction of $\ge $ and $\le$.